# Mongodb $in operator performing collscan instead of index scan on indexed field

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb, I am using Mongodb version - 5.0.9

I have a collection named User

```
User - 
{
    "_id" : "abcd",
    "name" : "Name"
}
```

Index -

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "User"
}
```

I am running this query and for some reason mongodb is doing CollScan instead of index scan. Can you help me what am I doing wrong here?

```
 q: { RecordLocator: { $in: [ "HKW", "HKW", "M0W", "M0W", "HLW", "HMW", "HMW", "AVW", "HNW", "M1W", "M1W", "CWW", "AVW", "HHW", "M4W", "CXW", "HMW", "HMW", "HMW", "CVW", "M2W", "AVW", "AVW", "M2W", "H8W", "M5W", "N6W", "HNW", "M2W", "CWW", "AVW", "H8W", "HPW", "HLW", "HMW", "M0W", "AVW", "CXW", "AVW", "M5W", "HPW", "HPW", "M0W", "C9W", "CVW", "A9W", "HMW", "HNW", "AVW", "AVW", "HNW", "CWW", "CWW", "CWW", "CWW", "MYW", "CTW", "MYW", "CTW", "MZW", "C9W", "MZW", "C9W", "MZW", "M0W", "A9W", "C9W", "HNW", "CVW", "HNW", "H8W", "MYW", "HKW", "C9W", "HLW", "M0W", "M0W", "M3W", "CWW", "GRW", "AVW", "G6W", "CXW", "M4W", "MZW", "HKW", "HKW", "C9W", "C9W", "A9W", "CVW", "A9W", "HMW", "H8W", "F1W", "AVW", "CWW", "H8W", "M3W", "AVW", "CWW", "M3W", "H8W", "AVW", "HGW", "M3W", "NBW", "H7W", "HJW", "MZW", "CVW", "CVW", "O1W", "HNW", "CTW", "CTW", "CTW", "HJW", "HKW", "C9W", "HMW", "HMW", "MZW", "C9W", "C9W", "C9W", "HLW", "C9W", "HLW", "C9W", "HMW", "B8W", "MZW", "MZW", "C9W", "M0W", "A9W", "H7W", "CTW", "C9W", "HJW", "MZW", "MZW", "MZW", "MZW", "EDW", "A9W", "HMW", "M1W", "HNW", "CWW", "CWW", "CXW", "M4W", "CWW", "AVW", "H8W", "H8W", "H8W", "CWW", "AVW", "CXW", "AVW", "CVW", "AVW", "M1W", "CWW", "CWW", "CWW", "M2W", "M3W", "CXW", "CVW", "CVW", "M1W", "HNW", "H8W", "HPW", "HPW", "HGW", "MYW", "MYW", "CTW", "MZW", "C9W", "HKW", "HKW", "A9W", "M0W", "M0W", "CVW", "M1W", "M1W", "M2W", "HPW", "AWW", "NCW", "AVW", "CYW", "AWW", "AWW", "AWW", "CZW", "HSW", "HSW", "AXW", "AXW", "AWW", "DJW", "HRW", "HRW", "HSW", "HSW", "HQW", "HQW", "CYW", "NHW", "HRW", "N7W", "CZW", "NJW", "NJW", "NJW", "HTW", "AXW", "C0W", "HTW", "AWW", "HRW", "CYW", "NHW", "NHW", "NHW", "NHW", "HSW", "HSW", "HSW", "HTW", "HTW", "NKW", "NEW", "NHW", "HRW", "AXW", "CZW", "NJW", "AXW", "CXW", "CYW", "NGW", "AWW", "HRW", "AWW", "HSW", "HSW", "NGW", "HQW", "CYW", "HRW", "NDW", "AXW", "CRW", "HTW", "NJW", "HTW", "AXW", "AYW", "NBW", "C0W", "C0W", "B0W", "HTW", "NLW", "NLW", "AYW", "H9W", "AXW", "HTW", "HTW", "AYW", "AYW", "H9W", "NMW", "C0W", "NJW", "AXW", "HTW", "AYW", "HTW", "C1W", "HTW", "H9W", "H9W", "H9W", "HVW", "HTW", "HTW", "NLW", "HTW", "C1W", "NLW", "H9W", "H9W", "NLW", "H9W", "NMW", "C2W", "AZW", "AXW", "C0W", "AXW", "AYW", "NKW", "AYW", "HTW", "C1W", "HTW", "NLW", "NLW", "NLW", "NLW", "HTW", "HTW", "HTW", "C1W", "NMW", "H9W", "NGW", "AWW", "HTW", "NKW", "C0W", "NKW", "NLW", "C1W", "HPW", "CXW", "D6W", "HRW", "FNW", "AXW", "AXW", "CZW", "AXW", "AXW", "C0W", "C0W", "AXW", "AWW", "CZW", "N0W", "HSW", "CZW", "HSW", "HTW", "AYW", "C2W", "HTW", "C0W", "AYW", "AYW", "H9W", "NBW", "HQW", "AWW", "HQW", "AWW", "HRW", "AXW", "CZW", "CZW", "AXW", "AXW", "CXW", "AWW", "NXW", "NHW", "AWW", "HSW", "N7W", "AXW", "AXW", "AXW", "C0W", "AVW", "AWW", "CYW", "NGW", "CYW", "CZW", "NHW", "N7W", "HSW", "HSW", "HTW", "NKW", "AYW", "HTW", "C0W", "HTW", "HTW", "HTW", "NKW", "NKW", "HTW", "H9W", "AXW", "AXW", "AXW", "HTW", "NKW", "C0W", "C0W", "NLW", "H9W", "HTW", "C0W", "HTW", "AXW", "C0W", "AYW", "NLW", "NDW", "CYW", "CYW", "AWW", "AWW", "HRW", "HSW", "HSW", "AXW", "NJW", "C0W", "NJW", "HTW", "NJW", "H9W", "H9W", "H9W", "H9W", "NLW", "CYW", "FVW", "NGW", "AWW", "NJW", "HTW", "HTW", "HTW", "NJW", "NKW", "NKW", "HTW", "HTW", "AZW", "C2W", "NBW", "CXW", "HRW", "NHW", "NHW", "AWW", "AXW", "AXW", "AXW", "CZW", "HTW", "AXW", "AYW", "C1W", "NLW", "H9W", "C2W", "H9W", "H9W", "NJW", "HSW", "HSW", "HTW", "C0W", "HTW", "HTW", "HTW", "HTW", "H9W", "C2W", "C2W", "AYW", "NMW", "NMW", "NMW", "AZW", "C4W", "H4W", "N8W", "N8W", "N8W", "I6W", "A0W", "A0W", "IBW", "A1W", "AZW", "H0W", "C3W", "A0W", "H5W", "LWW", "C4W", "N8W", "C5W", "A1W", "HVW", "NMW", "C3W", "AZW", "NMW", "NMW", "AZW", "C4W", "A0W", "C4W", "IBW", "NMW", "C3W", "NNW", "AZW", "C4W", "A0W", "C4W", "H5W", "LXW", "C5W", "A1W", "AZW", "AZW", "C3W", "NNW", "NNW", "C4W", "AZW", "I6W", "NPW", "NPW", "C5W", "NMW", "AZW", "AZW", "NMW", "HWW", "NNW", "A0W", "N8W", "ICW", "NMW", "C2W", "HVW", "AZW", "NNW", "AZW", "C3W", "C3W", "AZW", "C4W", "C4W", "C4W", "A1W", "D6W", "A1W", "HVW", "HVW", "JZW", "N8W", "H4W", "C4W", "AZW", "AZW", "HVW", "C3W", "NMW", "C3W", "H2W", "AZW", "A0W", "N8W", "NPW", "HWW", "NNW", "NNW", "H2W", "AZW", "N8W", "H4W", "C4W", "I6W", "A0W", "A0W", "A1W", "D6W", "A2W", "NQW", "A2W", "IFW", "NQW", "IGW", "DHW", "NRW", "IEW", "IEW", "A2W", "A2W", "A2W", "A3W", "A3W", "IGW", "NRW", "C2W", "HWW", "OLW", "H3W", "H3W", "H4W", "C4W", "N8W", "IBW", "IEW", "A2W", "NQW", "AZW", "NMW", "C3W", "NMW", "NNW", "H4W", "N8W", "IDW", "DBW", "DBW", "NQW", "DBW", "IEW", "A2W", "NQW", "IFW", "IGW", "IDW", "A1W", "D6W", "A2W", "DBW", "A2W", "A2W", "NQW", "IEW", "NQW", "IEW", "A2W", "DDW", "NQW", "A2W", "DGW", "C2W", "AZW", "HYW", "HZW", "H1W", "H1W", "AZW", "H2W", "C4W", "C4W", "C4W", "A0W", "C4W", "C4W", "A0W", "C4W", "A0W", "HWW", "C3W", "NNW", "AZW", "H0W", "AZW", "C4W", "N8W", "C4W", "N8W", "A0W", "C4W", "I6W", "N8W", "C5W", "NPW", "A2W", "D6W", "A2W", "A2W", "DDW", "NQW", "NQW", "DGW", "DHW", "A1W", "A1W", "IBW", "NPW", "IEW", "DBW", "NQW", "IFW", "A2W", "NQW", "DBW", "A2W", "NRW", "C3W", "C3W", "NNW", "C4W", "C4W", "C4W", "LWW", "C4W", "I6W", "NPW", "NPW", "IBW", "A1W", "ICW", "D6W", "D6W", "A1W", "NQW", "DDW", "DEW", "IFW", "NRW", "DGW", "NRW", "A0W", "IBW", "NPW", "DBW", "NQW", "A2W", "DFW", "A2W", "NRW", "A2W", "AZW", "N8W", "C4W", "H4W", "C5W", "ICW", "ICW", "NPW", "D6W", "IDW", "IEW", "LQW", "C5W", "IBW", "A1W", "A2W", "IEW", "DBW", "IEW", "NQW", "IBW", "ICW", "IDW", "D6W", "IEW", "IFW", "DGW", "DHW", "IFW", "A2W", "NQW", "NQW", "IEW", "A2W", "DFW", "NRW", "NRW", "NQW", "NRW", "IGW", "IGW", "DHW", "L9W", "DHW", "NRW", "NRW", "D7W", "IHW", "IHW", "I7W", "NTW", "DHW", "DHW", "NRW", "A4W", "D7W", "NTW", "A5W", "IJW", "DKW", "N9W", "IGW", "IHW", "IHW", "NSW", "DJW", "DKW", "A5W", "NTW", "A3W", "IHW", "DJW", "NSW", "O7W", "JSW" ] }
```

I saw few article that $ne and $nin operators are not selective ([here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why)). But what does that mean, I can't perform these queries on indexed field with index scan?

Comment: $in operation will use index , but from what you have posted you have fields _id(indexed) and name , but you search on RecordLocator field ... , maybe add the correct field names ...

Comment: Recordlocator is decorated with BsonId in C# model.

Answer (score 0):

Index do work for $in operator in mongodb, in my case my C# class didn't have [BsonId] decorator and once I added it on the RecordLocator property, it started working.

```
User {
  [BsonId]
  Public string RecordLocator {get; set;}

   Public string Name {get; set;}
}
```